# python write to file from a dictionary in batch

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently writing to a csv file from a dictionary - line by line. Like this:

```
writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'a'))
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

My problem is this: My dictionary gets big (say ~20 MB) and I am constrained by heap-space in my linux machine. So, instead of accumulating all data in my dictionary before I write it, I resorted to writing my data to csv file immediately when it becomes available -  from my dictionary (that is just one record long).

Now, I see another problem - time. Due to large number of IO operations (thousands of lines written to disk), my programs runs very slowly.

I need find a middle ground. Perhaps, accumulate 5000 (k,v) data in my dictionary and write it out to disk, flush my dictionary, wait for the next 5000 (k,v) pair, ...continue this process. Do you have any other ideas?

In short, is there a nice to write in batch into a file?

Thanks,
PD/

Comment: You get memory problems at 20 MB? Are you running it on an embedded system?

Comment: 5000 write and 20MB of data should be fast unless you are on a very crippled system. Is something else slow in your program. Try writing to /dev/null - if you have the same slowness, then its not your file writes causing the problem.

Comment: Your idea sounds very simple. Really, it's just adding an `if len(mydict) >= BATCH_SIZE:` before the code that writes out and then clears your dictionary. Just remember to write the final partial batch at the end. Are you looking for a buffered CSV wrapper to make that even easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be using DictReader/DictWriter.

```
for row in dictrows:
    out_f.write("%s%s" %(delimiter.join([row[name] for name in fieldnames]),
                lineterminator))
```

where dictrows is a generator of dictionaries produced by DictReader from csv, fieldnames is a list of fields.

Comment: apologies for the typo. The dict could grow to 20 GB.

Comment: @abarnet: My idea is simple and I think that would suffice. I was asking around if anyone has some cool tricks :-) Many times, I have seen simple solutions to be very effective.

Comment: I haven't used generators before and I am not well-versed with that yet. However, I shall read up and see how your suggestion might help. Thanks.